# Sincronizar dos bases mysql sin usar master y slave

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Necesito actualizar los datos en dos bases de datos de diferentes servidores pero que no sea con master slave
master me dice que debo de dejar bind IPSERVIDOR
normalmente yo lo dejo bind RED  o bind 0.0.0.0
porque los programadores se conectan a labase directamente
entonces no puedo dejarlo en master.
quisiera saber si existe un mecanismo para actualizar las bases sin ese proceso.
Gracias

Comment: Has pensado en usar la sintaxis de REMPLACE que tienes mysql, busca como se usa

Comment: Gracias. Eso hare.

Comment: Si estás escuchando en 0.0.0.0 eso abarca IPServidor

Comment: Sí, pero cundo se coloca en slave veo que exige su ip nada mas. la ip asignada a ese server.